# vue js event after rending is done

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table that is rendered by Vue. I want to apply datatable on it after it is rendered. Reason I am using Vue first is because its requires lot of custom functionality on each cell.

Whenever I call datatable function on table I get an error because vue is not finished rendering table.

Is there any way to know when Vue is done rendering all elements in  a dom so I can apply datatable on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `Vue.nextTick()`

Here is a sample from the docs:

```
// modify data
vm.msg = 'Hello'
// DOM not updated yet
Vue.nextTick(function () {
  // DOM updated
})
```

Reference: http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-nextTick